# Trouble with WinSCP & SISS. Execute Process Task Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, winscp, winscp-net

I am having difficultly with grabbing data from our WinSCP site through our SSIS software. Below is the Process I currently have

Executable: `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe Arguments /script=E:\SSIS\Union Street\SFTP.txt WorkingDirectory E:\SSIS\Union Street\Union Street V2`

Below is the error script I receive

> SSIS package "E:\SSIS\Union Street\Union Street V2\Union Street V2\Package.dtsx" starting.
> Error: 0xC0029151 at Execute Process Task, Execute Process Task: In **Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" "/script=E:\SSIS\Union Street\SFTP.txt" at "E:\SSIS\Union Street\Union Street V2", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".**
> Task failed: Execute Process Task
> Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
> SSIS package "E:\SSIS\Union Street\Union Street V2\Union Street V2\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.

Any help would be grateful

Comment: Try the command line version - winscp.com - rather than winscp.exe (which is the gui app). Or use the /console parameter.

Comment: I think you should go through [this](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax) and the Scripting and Automation section [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guides)

Comment: See WinSCP article  [Debugging transfer task running in Windows Scheduler, SSIS, or another automation service](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_debugging_scheduler).